# Why did change picture fail on a png file in my profile?

Tags: support, profile-picture

I tried to update my profile with a png image, which crashed.  Is png a supported filetype for the picture?  If not, would it be possible to alert users before clicking the upload button?

Comment: Can you describe how it crashed? PNGs are supported just fine.

Comment: It may be a failure on the imgur end - are you sure the image is a valid png?

Comment: How big is the file?